# forground service getting auto pause after 40 to 60 seconds

Tags: android, kotlin, location, background-service, foreground-service

i am working on location tracking app. this app is working fine in other conditions but when comes to forground its work only for few seconds or a minut. when i again come back to app forground will work again
*where am i missing or i am implimenting the method in worng way*
**NOte: i have tried differnts way but still same issue **

- implimenting alarm
- implimenting broadcast
- differnt way of forground service
- etc
  *but still i feel somewere i am doing wrong just help me to catch and guid me *
  this is my service class

  ```
  class TestForegroundService : Service() {
   lateinit var database: DatabaseReference

   //region data
   private val UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS: Long = 3000
   private var mFusedLocationClient: FusedLocationProviderClient? = null
   private var locationRequest: LocationRequest? = null
   private val locationSettingsRequest: LocationSettingsRequest? = null
   companion object {
    var isServiceRunning = false
    const val ACTION_START_FOREGROUND_SERVICE = "ACTION_START_FOREGROUND_SERVICE"
    const val ACTION_STOP_FOREGROUND_SERVICE = "ACTION_STOP_FOREGROUND_SERVICE"
    const val NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "YOUR_NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID"
   }

   //sharing location
   override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    initData()
   }

   // sharing location
   private val locationCallback: LocationCallback = object : LocationCallback() {
    override fun onLocationResult(locationResult: LocationResult) {
       super.onLocationResult(locationResult)
       val currentLocation: Location = locationResult.lastLocation
       Log.d(
           "Locations",
           currentLocation.getLatitude().toString() + "," + currentLocation.getLongitude()
       )
       //Share/Publish Location
     }
   }

   private fun initData() {
     locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
     locationRequest!!.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);
     locationRequest!!.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
     mFusedLocationClient =
       LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(application)
   }

   override fun onBind(p0: Intent?): IBinder? {
     return null
   }

   override fun onTaskRemoved(rootIntent: Intent?) {
     initAlarm()
     super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent)
   }

   private fun initAlarm() {
    val alarmMgr = getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
    val intent = Intent(this, TestForegroundService::class.java)
    val alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0)
    alarmMgr[AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() +
           2000] = alarmIntent
   }

  override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {

   when (intent?.action) {
       ACTION_START_FOREGROUND_SERVICE -> {
           isServiceRunning = true
           startForegroundService()
           createNotificationChannel()
           startLocationUpdates()
       }
       ACTION_STOP_FOREGROUND_SERVICE -> {
           isServiceRunning = false
           stopForeground(true)
           createNotificationChannel()
           stopSelf()
       }
   }
    return START_STICKY
   }

  //inside service sharing location
  private fun startLocationUpdates() {
  //        if (checkLocationPermission())
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
           this,
           Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
       ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
           this,
           Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
       ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
     ) {
       // TODO: Consider calling
       //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
       // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
       //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
       //                                          int[] grantResults)
       // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
       // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
       return
     }
      mFusedLocationClient!!.requestLocationUpdates(
        this.locationRequest!!,
        this.locationCallback, Looper.myLooper()!!
     )
   }

   private fun startForegroundService() {
    val pendingIntent = Intent(this, UserActivity::class.java).let {
       it.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
       PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, it, 0)
    }
     val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
       .setOngoing(true)
       .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
       .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
       .setContentTitle("TestForegroundService")
       .setContentText("This is content text of notification")
       .setChannelId(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
       .build()
     Toast.makeText(this, "${currentDAte()}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
     startForeground(1, notification)

    }

    private fun createNotificationChannel() {
     if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
       val serviceChannel = NotificationChannel(
           NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID,
           "Test Service Channel",
           NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
       )
       val notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager::class.java)
       notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(serviceChannel)
     }
  }

  fun currentDAte(): String {
   val sdfTime = SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss")
   return sdfTime.format(Date())
   }
  }
  ```

this is how i am calling service in userActivity class

```
 private fun shareLocation() {
    isLocationSharing = true
    val serviceIntent = Intent(this, TestForegroundService::class.java)
    serviceIntent.action = TestForegroundService.ACTION_START_FOREGROUND_SERVICE
    startService(serviceIntent)
 //        LocationServiceforground.startService(this, "service started")
    Toast.makeText(this@UserActivity, "location enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    location.visibility = View.GONE
    beingTrack.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    locationGif.visibility = View.VISIBLE
}
```

this is broadcastReceiver class

```
  class MyReceiver: BroadcastReceiver() {
   override fun onReceive(p0: Context?, intent: Intent) {
    val serviceIntent = Intent(p0, TestForegroundService::class.java)
                serviceIntent.action = TestForegroundService.ACTION_START_FOREGROUND_SERVICE
                p0!!.startService(serviceIntent)
    }
 }
```

**Thank you in Advance **

Answer (score 0):

On your phone, you can turn it on in settings>applications>autostart

Comment: what kind of answer is this

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sOc37XDJWr4) link explains how to get location updates continuously in the background even while not using the application OR screen is OFF